# Matching a number-range expression with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match an input of the following format

`[Number]-[Number]` using regex in JavaScript.

For ex :

1. `1-100` OK
2. `200-300` OK
3. `-0992` NOT OK
4. `aa-76` NOT OK
5. `1-` NOT OK

I tried:

```
^\d+(-\d+)*$
```

But this does not work at all.

Any pointers?

Comment: `[Number]-[Number]` isn't that specific, do you have any other qualifiers?

Comment: Edited My question with exact scenarios,hope it helps

Comment: Do you understand the pattern you have so far and why it can match `1` and `1-10-100-1000`?

Comment: @zx81 at first I thought the OP wanted to match the `0-100` range, but the second example contradicts the assumption.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Yes, you're right.

Comment: @JonathanLonowski I get it,i know the * makes the dash and following number optional and the $ allows this combination ,multiple times ,but i am writing these inside  validator script ,where the one i mentioned is not even matching the correct formats i.e. 1 or 1-100 or 1-00-1-99 .Hence considering i had committed some mistake i posted it for more opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you are looking for is `/\d+-\d+/`. If you don't require the whole line to match the regex, then there is no need for surrounding `^` and `$`. For instance:

```
/\d+-\d+/.test("a-100")
// Result: false
/\d+-\d+/.test("-100")
// Result: false
/\d+-\d+/.test("10-100")
// Result: true
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason it doesn't work is that the `*` quantifier makes the `(-\d+)` optional, allowing the regex to simply match `222`. Remove it and all will be well. If you don't need the parentheses, strip them:

```
^\d+-\d+$
```

**What if you want your numbers to be between 0 and 100 as in title?**

If you want to make sure that your numbers on each side are in the range from 1 to 100, without trailing zeros, you can use this instead of `\d`:

```
100|[1-9]\d|\d
```

Your regex would then become:

```
^(?:100|[1-9]\d|\d)-(?:100|[1-9]\d|\d)$
```

**What if the left number must be lower than the right number?**

The regexes above will accept `2222-1111` for the first, `99-12` for the second (for instance). If you want the right number to be greater than the lower one, you can capture each number with capturing parentheses:

```
^(\d+)-(\d+)$
```

or

```
^(100|[1-9]\d|\d)-(100|[1-9]\d|\d)$
```

Then, if there is a match, say

```
if(regexMatcher.group(2) > regexMatcher.group(1)) { ... success ...}
```